# Customers are getting redirected back on checkout page instead of order confirmation page

Tags: paypal, x-cart

We are using PayPal Express Checkout in our X-cart (Version 4.7.9, but not sure if its related to X-cart).

** Issue: ** We are showing "Checkout with PayPal" button on basket page of the website.

Basket image :
[image]

So when customers are clicking on "Checkout with PayPal" then below mentioned steps are appearing:

1) Redirecting on PayPal and customer are entering their PayPal details

2) Redirecting back to the checkout page and then again clicking on "Submit" button on the checkout page.

3) Then Order confirmation page is appearing.

So my question is that above-mentioned flow is correct? If Yes, then can you provide few links where flow mentioned or something similar?

Or its an issue, and user use should redirect to order confirmation page directly instead of coming back to the checkout page.

Please help me out with this flow. Supporting links and articles will be very useful.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if you got the money?

Comment: HI @AthrunZara , actually we were checking with sandbox account. Also it seem that payment will not be issue because we are getting order confirmation page. The issue issue is flow.

Comment: If you are asking a flow, that flow are correct for practice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow is correct as X-Cart has to recalculate the cart total at the step #2 based on a new address info provided by PayPal.

There are only 2 steps(#1 and #3) from checkout page as X-Cart can calculate exact cart total on this page.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It helps me.